# Python Doctest Outputchecker

Tags: python, django, doctest

I trying to run 1 project and receiving strange error when trying to run server or using make commands like

```
$ -u www-data make compilemessages
$ -u www-data bin/django collectstatic --noinput
```

or

> $ ./bin/django runserver

I always receiving this error message:

> class _NonManglingOutputChecker(doctest.OutputChecker):
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OutputChecker'

```
import doctest
import re

class _NonManglingOutputChecker(doctest.OutputChecker):
```

Last line witch throws error, how can i solve that?

Comment: Are you sure `doctest` in this case is the standard library module? What's `doctest.__file__`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure, this file goes from eggs/testtools/matchers/_doctest.py in witch imported doctest so, as i understand import doctest in this case is imported from default python lib ?